# connect to android client from servlet

Tags: android

Hi every bodyNow I have a problem connecting from servlet(or another  main methode in jse class) to Android client. How can I send a data to display from servlet? And how can I receive string data in Android

Answer (score 0):

This article http://wiebe-elsinga.com/blog/?p=405 describes several possible solutions:

- SOAP
- Direct Implementation (Probably what you want)
- JSON

I have used this code as a base very successfully.